# Swift generic Array KVO

Tags: swift, generics, key-value-observing

I have a generic array

```
dynamic var tasks : Array<Task> = []
```

I want it to be generic and dynamic so I can key value observe it. The following error shows up

```
Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C
```

I've tried adding @objc to the class that holds tasks and it inherits from NSObject but the error message does not go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that my class Task was not a subclass of NSObject.
Adding this removed the error.